# Save open files with new encoding in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I would like to save multiple files in Sublime Text 3 with a new character encoding.

I have tried using the following key command to achieve this with no luck. Basically nothing happens when I press the key combination.

```
{
 "keys" : ["ctrl+alt+s"],
 "command" : "save_all", "args" :{"encoding" : "Western (Windows 1252)"}
}
```

If I check the key binding in the console with `sublime.log_commands(True)` I can see that the key binding is working because it returns `command: save_all {"encoding": "Western (Windows 1252)"}` But Sublime Text is still not saving the file as Western (Windows 1252). If I reopen the file it says UTF-8.

Is this at all possible or is there perhaps something wrong with the key binding I am using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would guess that the `save_all` command doesn't support the `encoding` argument.

You can save all open files with a different encoding with a short python snippet.

---

For a single use, you could simply run the following in Sublime's python console:

```
[view.run_command('save', { "encoding": "Western (Windows 1252)" }) for view in window.views()]
```

---

To create a keybinding:

- Goto the `Tools` menu
- `Developer`
- `New Plugin...`

Replace the contents of the new file with the following:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class SaveAllWithEncodingCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, **kwargs):
        for view in self.view.window().views():
            view.run_command('save', kwargs)
```

Save it as `save_all_with_encoding.py` in the `Packages/User` folder (it should default to this folder when it shows the save as dialog...)

Then your keybinding will need to look like this:

```
{
   "keys" : ["ctrl+alt+s"],
   "command" : "save_all_with_encoding", "args" : {"encoding" : "Western (Windows 1252)" }
}
```

Comment: how do you know this? is this in some kind of documentation? sorry for the stupid question

Comment: Great, you saved my day.... Do you know where I can get a full list of all valid encoding values in the `"encoding" : "xxx"` pair?

Comment: @FaithReaper yes, just use https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer to view the `Packages/Default/Main.sublime-menu` file - all the encodings ST supports are part of the `File -> Reopen with Encoding` menu.

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant. Works in Sublime Text 2 as well, by the way.